# Matching dataframes with data.table

Tags: r, database, match, data.table

I need to fill a matrix (MA) with information from a long data frame (DF) using another matrix as identifier (ID.MA).

An idea of my three matrices:
MA.ID creates an identifier to look in the big DF the needed variables:

```
     a      b      c
a    ID.aa  ID.ab  ID.ac
b    ID.ba  ID.bb  ID.bc
c    ID.ca  ID.cb  ID.cc
```

The original big data frame has useless information but has also the rows that are useful for me to fill the target MA matrix:

```
ID     1990 1991 1992
ID.aa  10   11   12
ID.ab  13   14   15
ID.ac  16   17   18
ID.ba  19   20   21
ID.bb  22   23   24
ID.bc  25   26   27
ID.ca  28   29   30
ID.cb  31   32   33
ID.cc  34   35   36
ID.xx  40   40   55
ID.xy  50   51   45
....
```

MA should be filled with cross-information. In my example it should look like that for a chosen column of DF (let's say, 1990):

```
     a    b    c
a    10   13   16
b    19   22   25
c    28   31   34
```

I've tried to use match but honestly it didn't work out:

```
MA$a = DF[match(MA.ID$a, DF$ID),2]
```

I was recommended to use the `data.table` package but I couldn't see how that would help me.

Anyone has any good way to approach this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd row in your `a` column of the expected output be `19` instead of `25`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thank you for pointing out that typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your input are *dataframes*, then you could do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ma)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x = unlist(df[match(x,df$ID), "1990"]))
          , .SDcols = colnames(ma)]
```

which returns:

```
    a  b  c
1: 10 13 16
2: 19 22 25
3: 28 31 34
```

*Explanation*:

- With `setDT(ma)` you transform the *dataframe* into a *datatable* (which is an enhanced *dataframe*).
- With `.SDcols=colnames(ma)` you specify on which columns the transformation has to be applied.
- `lapply(.SD, function(x) x = unlist(df[match(x,df$ID),"1990"]))` performs the matching operation on each column specified with `.SDcols`.

---

An alternative approach with `data.table` is first transforming `ma` to a long *data.table*:

```
ma2 <- melt(setDT(ma), measure.vars = c("a","b","c"))
setkey(ma2, value)    # set key by which 'ma' has to be indexed
setDT(df, key="ID")   # transform to a datatable & set key by which 'df' has to be indexed

# joining the values of the 1990 column of df into
# the right place in the value column of 'ma'
ma2[df, value :=  `1990`]
```

which gives:

```
> ma2
   variable value
1:        a    10
2:        b    13
3:        c    16
4:        a    19
5:        b    22
6:        c    25
7:        a    28
8:        b    31
9:        c    34
```

The only drawback of this method is that the numeric values in the 'value' column get stored as character values. You can correct this by extending it as follows:

```
ma2[df, value :=  `1990`][, value := as.numeric(value)]
```

If you want to change it back to wide format you could use the `rowid` function within `dcast`:

```
ma3 <- dcast(ma2, rowid(variable) ~ variable, value.var = "value")[, variable := NULL]
```

which gives:

```
> ma3
    a  b  c
1: 10 13 16
2: 19 22 25
3: 28 31 34
```

---

Used data:

```
ma <- structure(list(a = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ID.aa", "ID.ba", "ID.ca"), class = "factor"), 
                     b = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ID.ab", "ID.bb", "ID.cb"), class = "factor"), 
                     c = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ID.ac", "ID.bc", "ID.cc"), class = "factor")), 
                .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:9, .Label = c("ID.aa", "ID.ab", "ID.ac", "ID.ba", "ID.bb", "ID.bc", "ID.ca", "ID.cb", "ID.cc"), class = "factor"), 
                     `1990` = c(10L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L), 
                     `1991` = c(11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 29L, 32L, 35L), 
                     `1992` = c(12L, 15L, 18L, 21L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 36L)), 
                .Names = c("ID", "1990", "1991", "1992"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: That was absolutely the best way to deal with my problem, @Jaap! Your answered rock! Thank you very very much!!

Comment: Did it :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

In base R, it can be seen as a job for `outer`:

```
> outer(1:nrow(MA.ID), 1:ncol(MA.ID), Vectorize(function(x,y) {DF[which(DF$ID==MA.ID[x,y]),'1990']}))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   19   22   25
[3,]   28   31   34
```

Explanations:

- `outer` creates a matrix as the outer product of the first argument `X` (here `a b c`) and the second argument `Y` (here the same, `a b c`)
- for every combination of `X` and `Y`, it applies a function that looks up the value in `DF`, at the row where the `ID` is `MA.ID[X,Y]`, and at the column `1990`
- the important trick here is to wrap the function with `Vectorize`, because `outer` expects a vectorized function
- the result is finally returned as matrix

---

Alternatively, another way to do it (still in base R) is:

1. to convert your data frame `MA.ID` into a vector
2. `sapply` a quick function that looks up correspondance with `DF$ID`
3. and convert back to a matrix.

This works:

```
> structure(
     sapply(unlist(MA.ID), 
            function(id){DF[which(DF$ID==id),'1990']}),
     dim=dim(MA.ID), names=NULL)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   19   22   25
[3,]   28   31   34
```

(here the call to `structure(..., dim=dim(MA.ID), names=NULL)` converts back the vector to a matrix)